# Calculating break point (bend) of a material

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, strength

I'm trying to compare a really tough polyurethane to baltic birch plywood to see if I can use it instead (a lot of subtractive processes to the plywood, want to eliminate it)

So what i'm looking for is how much weight it can carry per thickness and length
Currently i'm using 400mm X 100mm X 16mm blocks of plywood (then engrave it and so on)
And I know for a fact it can handle 100kg load with some bending but not breaking (weight in the middle)

[image]

This is the TDS of the material:
[image]

Is it possible to calculate?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the support information, the type, and number of applied loads and load locations.

Comment: Thanks, edited to give a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: If the tensile strength for the other material is greater, then the material behaves better and you can use longer and thinner planks.**

### Assumptions

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that :

- the breadth of the plank $b$ is a constant for both cases, and only the thickness $h$ and the distance between supports $L$ is changing.
- the load is a distributed load $w$ along the length of the material . In that case the distributed load $w $ is in units of $N/m$ and it includes the load on the shelf and the weight per meter of the plank.
- That you are interested only in strength. i.e. when the plank breaks.

### calculations

In that case the bending moment is
$M = \dfrac {wL^2}{8} $

The second moment of area for a rectangular cross-section is
$$I = \frac{bh^3}{12}$$

Then the  maximum stress in the beam is:

$$\sigma_{max} = \dfrac {M }{I }\cdot \dfrac {h }{2 } = \dfrac{12 w L^2 }{8 bh^2}$$

$$\sigma_{max} =  \dfrac{3 w L^2 }{2 bh^2}$$

The maximum stress $\sigma_{max} $ needs to be less than the allowable stress for the material $\sigma_{all}$  in order to avoid the failure.

$$\sigma_{max} \le \sigma_{all} $$
I'll save you the analysis, you end up with

$$\dfrac{L }{h}\le \sqrt{\dfrac{2 b}{3 w }\sigma_{all}} $$

For this case, since comparison is required, the limiting case is taken ie. :
$$\dfrac{L }{h} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2 b}{3 w }\sigma_{all}} $$

From here you can see that (**for the uniform loading case**)the length L and the thickness $h$ have a competing relationship. I.e. when the length increases, the thickness also needs to increase proportionally, in order to fail at the same breaking load.

### Bottom line

Higher values of the ratio $\frac{L}{h}$ means  that you can have longer beams with thinner planks.

Assuming the load $w$ and the breadth $b$ is constant, then you can see that the ratio $\frac{L}{h}$ is proportional to $\sqrt{\sigma_{all}}$. i.e.:

$$\frac{L}{h} \propto \sqrt{\sigma_{all}}$$

where for the material you are considering (from the TDS) $\sigma_{all}$ is the tensile strength is between $41$ and $46$ [MPa].

If the tensile strength for the other material is greater, then the material behaves better and you can use longer and thinner planks.

### Caveats

This is a simplified analysis and there are a few assumptions for convenience (which -IMHO- are realistic  and do not invalidate the analysis).

- The first one is the type of load (uniform distributed load)
- The second is that the plywood behaves a bit differently that the polyurethane (one exhibits composite material behavior, while the latter behaves more like a uniform material).

Comment: Amazing!

So from here http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet_print.aspx?matguid=bd6620450973496ea2578c283e9fb807

The tensile of plywood is 27.6 - 34.5 MPa which means for the same L and h the plywood will break first?

Also what do you mean by behaviour? (composite vs uniform)

Comment: Yes about the plywood. Regarding the composite it means that the plywood comes into layers which individual layer has a different behaviour at different directions. As a whole though you can regard plywood as isotropic

Comment: I think it is more prudent to lump the block weight into the concentrated load or specify the calculation is valid for uniform distributed load only.

Answer (score 1):

Assume simply supported beam stressed to the ultimate state (plastic hinge has formed in the midspan), and deflection is not a concern.

[image]

Let $b =$ block width $(mm)$, $h =$ block thickness $(mm)$, $\rho=$ bulk density of the material $(kg_f/mm^3)$.

$w =$ uniformly distributed weight of the block $= \rho bh$

$M = \dfrac {PL}{4} + \dfrac {wL^2}{8} = \dfrac{2PL+\rho bhL^2}{8}$

$\sigma_{max} = f_y = \dfrac {4M}{bh^2} = \dfrac{2PL+\rho bhL^2}{2bh^2}$

$h = \sqrt {\dfrac {4M}{bf_y}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2PL+\rho bhL^2}{2bf_y}}$

As there is the unknown $"h"$ on both sides of the equation, the way to find it is first to determine the force $"P"$, then iterate the $"h"$ on the right side until the $"h"$ on both sides converge.

Note: If you prefer the extreme faces of the block is stressed to yield but remains elastic, change the equation to:

$h = \sqrt {\dfrac {6M}{bf_y}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2PL+\rho bhL^2}{3bf_y}}$

Also, for either case, it is prudent to provide a factor of safety. I recommend the safety factor should be around 1.5. For both cases (ultimate or elastic), $h_{provide} = 1.5h$.

Comment: Wow, thanks! this is more than I understand, anyway you can help me with the calculation?

Comment: It looks intimidating but not that difficult. I have provided the respective units that are to be used, you just need to plug in the terms with values in consistent units and watch out for conversions, such as 1 m = 1000 mm, 1 Pa = 1 kg_f/M^2. I am not quite certain on the difference between "Flexural Strength" and "Tensile Strength", so make sure you know which one is the Yield Strength, f_y. Also, you need to find out the unit weight (density) of the material. Give it a try. Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: I have no idea how  how to find density, what strength to use and so on...

Comment: Sorry, couldn't help it.